# How to link two NSViews with a bezier curve?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, prototype

I am building a language learning macOS app and I was wondering how would I be able to link two `NSView`s with a bezier curve via `mouseDown` and `mouseUP` like the prototyping Flinto app for Mac (https://www.flinto.com/mac)? Both Objective-C and Swift are fine. Cheers!

Just adding a photo of the example for clarity...

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this? I saw the video in the link but which bit are you referring to? Are you just wanting to draw a bezier path between two views? Or do you want to animate between them using a custom easing curve?

Comment: Hi Fogmeister, thanks for your reply. I'm pretty much trying to figure out the interaction between two NSViews and drawing a line in between, kind of like in 0:22-0:23 in the video. For example, click NSView A (mouseDown then mouseUp) then click NSView B (mouseDown then mouseUP) and a line forms in between those two views.